# LilyPond: Allow dynamics (or other outside-staff objects) within the staff

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I tried

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

{ 
  \dynamicUp
  \once \override DynamicLineSpanner.staff-padding = #0
  \once \override DynamicLineSpanner.Y-offset = -3
  b'\f
}
```

and

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

{ 
  \dynamicUp
  \once \override DynamicLineSpanner.staff-padding = #0
  \once \override DynamicLineSpanner.Y-offset = -4
  b'\f
}
```

But that doesn't seem to suffice and the dynamic just skips to under the staff above a certain threshold.

Is there a way to allow dynamics to touch the staff, like in the following example?

[image: Dynamic partly within the staff]

Ideally this would be obtained with all other grobs adjusting to this change, so if I'm not mistaken extra-offset is not a solution.

This is a wider view of the traditional engraving:

[image: Traditional engraving]

And this is the (less satisfying) best approximation I've managed on Lilypond:

[image: Lilypond approximation: Not as satisfying]

Comment: Why do you want the dynamic mark inside the staff?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace The same reason traditional engravers use that: space economy and sometimes esthetics (e.g. to avoid a single dynamic marking in a system create an unseemly gap between the staff and some other outside-staff layer like a tempo marking or some other text script). Added more screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to disable staff collision avoidance for the dynamic marking (or any outside-staff object) isn't by turning the `staff-padding` of the `DynamicLineSpanner` to `#0` but its `outside-staff-priority` to `##f`.

I deduced that from the [LilyPond Learning Manual: 4.4.3 Outside-staff objects](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/learning/outside_002dstaff-objects), particularly from the part under "The `outside-staff-priority` property" where they talk about slurs and articulations.

The dynamic will then be centered in the staff. The `Y-offset` can then be modified with an `\override` and the `X-offset` with a `\tweak` (per [LilyPond Notation Reference: 4.6.2 Changing spacing](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/changing-spacing)) like so:

```
\version "2.22.1"
\language "english"

{ 
  \dynamicUp
  \once \override DynamicLineSpanner.outside-staff-priority = ##f
  \once \override DynamicLineSpanner.Y-offset = #2
  b'-\tweak X-offset #-0.75 \f
}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Yes. Generally by having a value for `outside-staff-priority` gives the grob the outside-staff-interface, thus Lilypond will not allow it to intersect with the staff.